# Why does this card flip animation only work after the first time?

Tags: css

I have a card flipping animation where there are 4 elements. A bottom / top half of the number 1, and a bottom / top half of the number two. It should end up looking similar to http://flipclockjs.com/.

The problem is that the bottom half of the number 2 only appears once the animation completes the first time, then it works like it should after that.

EDIT: ok I edited the code a bit, and it works just fine in Safari, but the bug is still present in Chrome, unless I remove the backface-visibility from `bot-two`; however, this causes the backface of the bottom half of two to appear for a split second at the end of the animation (but only in Safari).

```js
setInterval(() => {
  for ( const e of document.getElementsByClassName('item')) {
    e.classList.toggle('flip')
  }
}, 1000)
```

```css
html,body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: perspective(1000px);
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.item {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #444;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  will-change: transform;
}

.top-one {
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.top-one.flip {
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}

.bot-one {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.bot-one.flip {
  opacity: 0;
}

.bot-two {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  border-top: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.bot-two.flip {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}

.top-two {
  height: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}


.top-two {
  z-index: 1;
}

.top-one {
  z-index: 2;
}

.bot-one {
  z-index: 3;
}

.bot-two {
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item bot-two">2</div>
  <div class="item top-two">2</div>
  <div class="item top-one">1</div>
  <div class="item bot-one">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code does a strange behavior on FireFox.